# Can't figure out how to get JSON data

Tags: java, json, angularjs

I can’t get JSON data in Angular js from java file. Where is the mistake?

Store.java

```
...
@GetMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Object getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }
...
```

Main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myShoppingList', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/').
        then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            console.log(data);
        });
});
```

[image]

Updated:

I changed my code. And i don't have errors now but still can not get response.data

```
@GetMapping(value = "/products", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<Object> getProducts() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.products, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

```
var app = angular.module('myShoppingList', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/products').
        then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            console.log(data);
        });
});
```

Comment: What's kind of response did you get? A response with status code 404? Or with status code 200 but a null response body? Please provide more information so that we can help you!

Comment: just added a screenshot

Comment: `$http.get` returns a promise, you have to handle the `success` and `error` cases of promise individually.

Comment: Is your Java service (assuming Spring Boot) actually running on port 8080? FYI, you probably want to add the `@ResponseBody` annotation to your Java controller method

Comment: Yes. But still can't get response